# Multiple different intents based on position in arraylist item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, arraylist

I have been searching for a long time and still didn't find any solutions yet.
What I want is when you click on one of this custom listitems https://prnt.sc/flwqe3 that every list item when you click on it have his own intent .

if someone knows the answer pls let me know.

this is the activty with the custom listitems

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout._main);

        //Set the titel of the actionbar
        TextView actionbartitel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_titel);
        Typeface  = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/.ttf");
        actionbartitel.setTextSize(30);
        actionbartitel.setTypeface();
        actionbartitel.setText("");

        //set the back button of the actionbar
        ImageView actionbarimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_logo);
        actionbarimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
        // Set a click listener on that View
        actionbarimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // The code in this method will be executed when the family category is clicked on.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Create a new intent to open the {@link FamilyActivity}
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Activity.this, MainActivity.class);

                // Start the new activity
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });


        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });


        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayList<Subjects>  = new ArrayList<Subjects>();

        .add(new Subjects("", "", R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "5:60", 0xff00ffff,
                Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Font.ttf"), Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/timeFont.ttf")));

        .add(new Subjects("", " " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + " ", R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "5:60", 0xff0000ff,
                Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Font.ttf"), Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/timeFont.ttf")));


        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.classicmprogressbar);
            loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you refer each item of Array List has own intent and ArrayList Has Subject class object what you can do, In the `Subject` class you can add a `Class` object like  `Class cls;`
and add it to the `arrayList` thus:

`ArrayList<Subjects> subjects  = new ArrayList<Subjects>();`

```
    .add(new Subjects("", "", R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "5:60", 0xff00ffff,
            Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Font.ttf"), Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/timeFont.ttf"),IntentOne.class));

    .add(new Subjects("", " " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + " ", R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "5:60", 0xff0000ff,
            Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Font.ttf"), Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/timeFont.ttf"),IntenTwo.class));
```

and On List Item click you can access using following code

```
// Create a new intent to open the {@link FamilyActivity}
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Activity.this, adapter.getItem(position).cls);

            // Start the new activity
            startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Comment: I edited the subjects and added the classes to the list items

Comment: final WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, obsclassiclist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Create a new intent to open the {@link FamilyActivity}
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ObsclassicActivity.this, adapter.getItem(position).cls);

                // Start the new activity
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }

Comment: when I click still nothing happends is there something not right with my listener

Comment: you need to add listener to listView ie listView.setOnItemClickListener

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fm2kff this is the listener that I currently have in the activity when I press on it nothing still happends